# Failure to perform the update correctly in Mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want the third element of the matches to be updated but the first element have been updated!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
db.getCollection('users').update(
{
    "user": "javid","matches._id":"4","matches.week":"5","matches.league":"iran"
},
{
    "$set": {"matches.$.point": 7}
});
```

the document after execute query

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d0544a6739fcf22c0d8d263"),
"user" : "javid",
"pass" : "123456",
"email" : "erfa@f",
"total_point" : 19,
"rank" : 2,
"matches" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "1",
        "week" : "5",
        "league" : "iran",
        "ghome" : "3",
        "gaway" : "1",
        "point" : 7.0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "2",
        "week" : "5",
        "league" : "iran",
        "ghome" : "4",
        "gaway" : "1",
        "point" : 2
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "4",
        "week" : "5",
        "league" : "iran",
        "ghome" : "3",
        "gaway" : "1",
        "point" : "0"
    }
]
}
```

Please help me!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Your update looks ok. What do you mean by "but the first element to be updated"?

Answer (score 0):

you can only do one operation on an array path at a time. but you can achieve a single command if you use the bulkwrite interface like below:

```java
db.users.bulkWrite([
    {
        updateOne: {
            filter: {
                "user": "javid"
            },
            update: {
                "$set": {
                    "matches.0.point": 7
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        updateOne: {
            filter: {
                "user": "javid"
            },
            update: {
                "$pull": {
                    "matches": {
                        "_id": "3"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

here's a test program in c# that generated the above command:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    [Name("users")]
    public class User : Entity
    {
        public string user { get; set; }
        public match[] matches { get; set; }
    }

    public class match
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public int point { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            DB.Update<User>()

              .Match(u => u.user == "javid")
              .Modify(u => u.matches[0].point, 7)
              .AddToQueue()

              .Match(u => u.user == "javid")
              .Modify(b => b.PullFilter(u => u.matches, m => m._id == "3"))
              .AddToQueue()

              .Execute();
        }
    }
}
```